# Running custom DNS on EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, internal-dns

I am trying to design a Enterprise Hybrid DNS architecture, similar to this blog article:
https://medium.com/statuscode/hybrid-dns-for-the-enterprise-in-aws-5ba5a049bcb1

In summary there is an on-premise DNS zone(e.g. example.com) and a Route53 private hosted zone(e.g. cloud.example.com).

The goal is to run a custom DNS service using Bind DNS in AWS. Using DHCP options to point all EC2 instances to use the custom DNS services and have forwarders from inside to these custom DNS services. All the above is working as expected.

My concern is using the private IP address of the EC2 instances in the DHCP options as the EC2 instance could be terminated and IP is lost.
In addition, I would like to be able to scale vertically and add additional Bind DNS servers.

How can I create a load balancer in AWS for DNS services that has a fixed IP address that I can add to the DHCP options?

Comment: Are you running into Route 53 limitations that'd make doing this worthwhile? You're talking about a pretty big, complex chunk of infrastructure that's rarely necessary.

Comment: Yes. Using a direct connect VPN from on premise network to the AWS VPC, I cannot set a forwarder on the internal bind servers directly to Route53 for internal systems to resolve records in cloud.example.com zone. In addition the ec2 bind systems are configured with a forwarder for example.com back to the internal bind servers. Goal is to provide resolution to internal systems and EC2 VPC systems to the private hosted zone in route53(cloud.example.com) and the internal hosted zone(example.com)

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with a Network Loadbalancer, balancing port `53 tcp` AND `53 udp`.
Add your DNS Servers to a Target Group, and point the Network Loadbalancer towards that Target Group.

But I'd also sugesst to use NS glue records pointing to route53 NS or route53 VPC internal NS.

Comment: I did investigate a NLB however a NLB doesn't provide a private IP(s) that can be used in the DHCP options for EC2 instance rather it provides a DNS name. In addition BIND9 only supports IP address for forwaders so the internal BIND servers cannot forward to a DNS name

Comment: That's due to the scaling of the loadbalancers. Having high load would add additional IP's when scaling the loadbalancer up and remove them when scaling down.

Comment: This is the crux of my issue, DHCP options and BIND forwarder configuration want a forward IP(s) but there is no option for this it appears using AWS tools

Answer (score 0):

Based on your second comment:
* Point all Servers towards example.com DNS Server
* Add a glue record for zone cloud.example.com pointing to AWS Route53 Nameservers.
* Use route53 to manage cloud.example.com

That should do the job.

Comment: The problem is the route53 name servers will only respond to queries from within a VPC thus I can't forward queries from internal bind servers directly to route53 over the direct connect vpn

Comment: VPC internal DNS Servers are only reachable from inside the according subnet. Reaching through from outside is possible with natting the requests. iptables with two/three rules could do that job.

Comment: Using iptables to NAT into the reserved .2 route53 address would be an option however that doesn't provide any option to scale. In addition dedicated EC2 instances would be needed and this option wouldn't provide a solution for DNS forwarding to the internal zone example.com from the AWS VPC